# Global instance method

Tags: objective-c

I created a an instance method in my MainMenu init.

```
-(NSString*) iPhoneiPadConversionString: (NSString*) fileNameHold : (char) fileType {

....My Code.
}
```

All I want to do is reuse this method in my other classes....

```
fileName = [self iPhoneiPadCOnversionString: @"background.png": 'B'];
```

But I can't seem to figure out what the right stuff to do is... I have been trolling the board and can't quite put all the information together.  Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Awful method name.  Bare colons are highly discouraged.  Try `iPhoneiPadConversionString:type:`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a called a "category". With categories you can extend NSString (and add your method).
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html